# Открытие кодировки UTF-8

Tags: utf-8

Как открыть кодировку текстового файла utf-8 в far, чтобы удалить bom (необходима последовательность комбинаций клавиш)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыв файл в редакторе, нажмите Shift-F2. Там можно снять галочку напротив Add Signature (BOM).

Этот вопрос [обсуждался на форуме Far Manager](http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=5094)